# Source environment file not working in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this line in a Dockerfile

`RUN /bin/bash -c ". setup.sh ; echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ; make"`

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set in setup.sh. However, when I run `docker build .` the echo instruction just prints an empty string, and `make` gives an error for a library not found.

From many answers found here in Stackoverflow and elsewhere, I would expect the path to be printed out.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What happens if you escape the variable in the Dockerfile... `echo \$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or replace it with an `env`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Apparently yes, the problem of the echo instruction was that I wasn't escaping the dollar symbol, and the missing library in `make` was unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Dockerfile, the line:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c ". setup.sh ; echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ; make"
```

will result in the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable being expanded by docker itself (you can set that variable with an `ARG` or `ENV` line). To get the variable to be expanded by the shell inside your container, simply escape it with a backslash:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c ". setup.sh ; echo \$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ; make"
```

Comment: Thanks BMitch. Accepted